# UnsatisfiedLinkError /tmp/librocksdbjni*.so can't find in kafka streams in suse 11 sp4

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

My Kafka streams application can be run in ubuntu 16.04, but when I run it in suse 11 sp4, it doesn't run.

I use Kafka Streams 1.1.1 and rocksdb 5.7.3, I can find the librocksdbjni.so in rocksdb's jar, but it doesn't copy it to /tmp.

I find some similar question in stackoverflow but they are low version of Kafka streams or about windows, AIX and so on, It doesn't resolve my question.

Comment: You really shouldn't put shared objects into /tmp/

Comment: I've seen this error myself but in a slightly different context. Would you be able to share the trace of the error? just to see if there is any clue hidden in there.